# Best way of mimicking Scala Option[T] in Julia?

Tags: julia

If think that Scala Option[T] is quite useful to handle some exceptions, so I would like to use this concept in Julia as well.

For example, if we write the following Scala code in Julia,

```scala
def div(x: Double, y: Double): Option[Double] = {
  if (y == 0.0) None else Some(x / y)
}
```

I guess the following code would do the job, but is there any better of doing this?

```
function div(x:: Float64, y:: Float64):: Array{Union{Float64, Missing}}
  if (y == 0.0)
   [missing]
  else
   [x / y]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Julia, `Union` is only an *untagged* union, which makes a bit of a difference.

In your case, `missing` might be a very idiomatic solution, depending on the application -- the purpose of `missing` is to get propagated through following operations, like a chain of `map` would in Scala:

```
div(1.0, 0) + 1 === missing
```

can be compared to

```
div(1.0, 0).map(_ + 1) == None
```

But note that this happens automatically, until you hit some function that doesn't know `missing`.  (Note that even `x == missing` evaluates to `missing`!) Think of propagating `null`.

The other variant, which is a bit more like `Option[T]`, is `Union{Some{T}, Nothing}`.  This type will force you to explicitely take care of handling both cases: `Some` needs to be unwrapped, and `nothing` does not get propagated and will error soon.  This has somewhat different semantics, too: `missing` is more like a `N/A` value in data handling, while `Some`/`nothing` come closer to `Option` for things that might or might not exist (e.g., the head of a possibly empty list).

Note that often, just `Union{T, Nothing}` is used.  This in most cases makes no difference in semantics, and is easier to handle: due to `Union` being untagged, `T <: Union{T, Nothing}`, and values behave just like plain `T`.  But if you need to distinguish a `nothing` with `None` semantics from a `nothing` with `T` semantics, which can occur in generic functions, you need the additional `Some` layer to get `Some(nothing)` and `nothing`.

Comment: thanks for great answer especially pointing out x == missing gives missing

Comment: From 1.3 on, there's also `Base.ismissing`.