# Implementing the Option Functor in Julia - while maintaining type stability

Tags: generics, functional-programming, julia, option-type, functor

First off, I have created the following attempt at an `Option`-type in Julia:

```
# building an Option-type
abstract type MyNothing end
struct None{T} <: MyNothing end
Option = Union{Some{T},None{T}} where {T}
```

I wanted to construct it such that it would faithfully mimic how Option works in Scala (and how Maybe works in Haskell).  Specifically, I wanted to make sure that the `None` part of `Option` retained information about the type potentially held by `Some`.  I didn't want to fall in the pitfall of having a `None` that behaved like a null-pointer (hence, the whole point of using Option in the first place!).

So my first question is, is there a better/cleaner way to construct `Option`?

My next issue is that in my implementation of `fmap`, I had to evaluate the function that is passed to it in order to determine the appropriate return-type.  I tried to use `Base.return_types`, but it is way too flaky.  When I'd use it, it was far too apt to throw out `Any` as the type and it would break my implementation.

Here is the function definition for `fmap`:

```
# implementation of Functor for Option
function fmap(X::Functor{Option}, obj, fun)
    if typeof(obj) <: None
      par_type_in = param_type(obj)
      par_type_out = outtype(par_type_in, fun)
      None{par_type_out}()
    else
      obj |> something |> fun |> Some
    end
end
```

A few explanations:

- `param_type` extracts the generic, parametric type "held" by an object
- `outtype` returns the return type of a function (given an input-type and a function)
- In order to get `outtype` to work, I created a trait with a method `default`, that returns a default value for a specific type (thank you for the idea, Rust!).  Given that this is a functional programming topic, it's not lost on me that I could have equivalently created a `Monoid` trait.

This leads to my primary question - is there a better way to maintain type stability?  As I mentioned before, using `Base.return_types` was too unreliable.  My current approach works, but feels a little convoluted.  Furthermore, my current approach breaks-down when my specified default-values are edge-cases for functions fed to `fmap`.

Here are some sample function calls:

```
julia> x = Some(7)
Some(7)

julia> f = t -> string(6*t)
#3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> fmap(x,f)
Some("42")

julia> y = None{Int64}()
None{Int64}()

julia> fmap(y,f)
None{String}()
```

Notice that the implementation properly tracks the "contained" type for `None`.

A "minimal" working version of my attempt is tucked away in a Go playground (just as a quick and easy way to hold and share the code) below:

[Implementation of the Option Functor in Julia](https://go.dev/play/p/TIHUSQcN3Gy)

I was expecting that there would/should be a better and more reliable built-in way to determine the return-type of a function in Julia.  As I alluded to previously, I attempted to use `Base.return_types` but it failed.  What I ended up resorting to was rather involved, requiring the evaluation of the function to ascertain the return type.  To achieve this, I created a `Default` trait so that I could prescribe default values for various types.

I was displeased by the added complexity to the code.  I'm hoping that I'm just being obtuse and that there is a better/cleaner way to achieve the same objective.

I'd add that the following stack overflow post is related to this one, but doesn't quite address my question in the detail that I desire.

[Best way of mimicking Scala Option[T] in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040659/best-way-of-mimicking-scala-optiont-in-julia)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be because Julia's focus on multiple dispatch does not require compiler track knowledge of the return type in identifying a method as unique, just the function arguments.

To make sure your return type is in the function's type signature, you could, al la Julia's print(), not return anything from your functions that may return a None, and instead return values via some kind of reference to your return value in the function's signature.  So for example fmap could become

```
ret = [Option...(specify types here)]
function fmap(X::Functor{Option}, obj, fun, ret)
    ...
end
```

and you replace the contents of ret with your return value at function return. This lets Julia incorporate your return type in its function signature, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion.  If I understand you correctly, you're recommending using a pass-by-reference argument, so that I might be able to leverage the strength of Julia's type-inference for function arguments (seeing that multiple dispatch is a driving paradigm for the language).   A caveat with this suggestion is that fmap is an implemented method for the `Functor` trait.  None of the other implementations are pass-by-reference.  If I were to write things in idiomatic Julia, I would need to write a separate implementation for the `Option` type and then name the function `fmap!`.

Comment: Another caveat with the suggestion is that the whole code is mostly intended to be written within the functional-programming paradigm.  Consequently, trying to solve the issue by using "side-effects" seems counter to the intent.  Of course, my intent could be perceived as a little silly given that Julia is a dynamically typed language ... and I'm trying to have more tight control on return-type.